# Unable to run application on Docker if used any other port except default port 80

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have a demo app which is hosted on docker. The exposed port for Docker is 80 and the app is running fine on local machine and I am able to see landing page for my app on localhost:8888.

Docker file is as given below

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
COPY dist /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "demoapp.dll"]
```

Whenever I change line "EXPOSE 80/tcp"  to  for ex- "EXPOSE 8080/tcp" , "EXPOSE 5000/tcp" etc to expose any other port except 80 of Docker container as given in many online available sample codes, I am unable to run my app on browser. Any port except 80 is not working.

I am able to create image and create container for application too. Everything goes well but when I try to run app on browser (localhost:8080/5000/9000 etc.) The app landing page doesn't load.

Any suggestions? Do I need to do some port related configuration or contact my network team? or any code which I am missing here?

Comment: how are you running the docker container?

Comment: i am running command "docker run -d -p 8888:5000 mydemo:tag".

Answer (score 1):

For `microsoft/aspnetcore`, it sets the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable to `http://+:80` which means that if you have not explicity set a URL in your application, via app.UseUrl in your Program.cs for example, then your application will be listening on port 80 inside the container.

Reference: [microsoft/aspnetcore](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/)

If you want to change the default port 80, you need to use `UseUrls` in `Program.cs` with  like below, and use `EXPOSE 8080/tcp`  in dockerfile.

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseUrls("http://+:8080")
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Or, you need to change `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment like

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
COPY dist /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "demoapp.dll"]
```

Command to run

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 mytest
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to expose any port inside the container.
However you publish the exposed port on the host during the start of the container.
This is done with the `-p` flag of the `docker run` command.

When you say you are able to access the application using `localhost:8888` it means you have run the docker run command with `-p 8888:80`. This publishes the container port 80 onto the host as port 8888.
To use any other port just change the `docker run` command to `-p 8888:<new exposed port>` and that should do it.

See the docker run command help for more info:
https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/edge/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p-expose

> Publish or expose port (-p, –expose)
>
> $ docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:8080 ubuntu bash
>
> This binds port 8080 of the container to port 80 on
> 127.0.0.1 of the host machine. The Docker User Guide explains in detail how to manipulate ports in Docker.

Comment: "docker run -d -p 8888:80 mydemo:tag". This runs fine when i run localhost:8888 but the issue is that when i run "docker run -d -p 8888:5000 mydemo:tag" localhost:8888 doesn't load the page.

Comment: It also depends on what the process inside the conatiner is listening to. you need to be able to tell the process/app to listen on 5000 and only then the expose would be meaningful. If not, you just end up exposing the 5000 port but the process is listening to 80.

Answer (score 0):

If your application runs at port suppose `8080` then make sure to do port mapping while running the container.

`docker run -itd -p 8080:8080 <image>`

This will map port `8080` of host on port `8080` inside the container. (-p hostport:containerport)

If you don't want port mapping then run docker container in `host` mode.

`docker run -itd --net=host <image>`

In this case your container use host network, so whatever port your application is running inside it should get exposed.

Comment: I already did port mapping using "docker run -d -p 8888:8080 mydemo:tag" .